# finding UI objects in xcode UI object library

Tags: ios, xcode, uicontrol

this is a *serious* newbie question

i was just in xcode and had a detail table view (or possibly a cell within it) in a detail view controller highlighted...i had the code snippet library up in the Utilities panel.  i switched to the objects library, and lo and behold were a bunch UI objects i had never seen in the list...these included radio buttons, a color well, and on and on...very useful stuff i had never seen in that list before.  i navigated back to the storyboard and then came back to the object library, and this useful stuff was gone, replaced by the usual View Controller, Table View Controller, Collection View Controller, etc. list.  i pulled down the Objects dropdown at the top of the object library, and saw no way to navigate to that prior list of very useful objects...

i searched using google, at stackoverflow, and the apple site and still haven't found, apparently, the right way to ask the question.  apparently the object list in the Utilities pane is context sensitive, but try though i might, i have not yet figured out what needs to be highlighted in the storyboard to give me back that very valuable list of UI objects...any help deeply, and embarassedly (if that is a word) appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you saw that OS X controls for the first time :)

Answer (score 0):

May be that was Mac OS controls. Sometimes it show up. Me too don't know when exactly it comes up. but if you are creating iOS app then you don't need that. it can't be used in iOS app. so its good that you leave that.

Cheers!!